# Force download audio file in ASP.NET using public path

Tags: asp.net, file, audio, download

does any one knows how to force the downloa of a file with the "...Save As" window using a public path, for example:

www.domain.com/audio/myfile.mp3

I have found a lot of examples but using a virtual path and noth a public path.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do some IIS url rewrite voodoo to pull this off. You could easily do some URL routing to make it look like you are downloading from /audio/file.mp3 but are actually pulling the file through a special handler.

But if you are just serving a file with a mimetype there isn't a whole lot you could do -- the client really controls how they handle files when not instructed and you've got no instructions on how to handle it if you are just posting files for download in a directly accessible manner.